# Can I pass a presigned URL to another s3 bucket to use to download content to it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So as the question states, is there any means by which I can simply pass a url to an s3 bucket, and it will commence the download of that content?  As if I was sending a file to an upload presigned url generated by my bucket, but instead the url.

something like this:

`s3Client.uploadeToS3FromGivenUrl(s3BucketName, downloadFromThisUrl)`

Help appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "pass a url to an s3 bucket" and "passing a file"? Can you perhaps edit your question and explain the end-result of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: i have edited to further explain and added a piece of imaginary code to help support it.  My goal is not to download any content into my stack, but to effectively move a piece of data from one s3 bucket to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [CopyObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_CopyObject.html) API call to copy an object between buckets if you have sufficient access permissions.

However, if you can only read permissions **via a pre-signed URL**, this will not work. You will need to **download the object and then upload it** to the destination bucket.